# HTML Validator that outputs csv or similar

Tags: html, validation, csv, spreadsheet

I have been given the horrid task of trying to clean up the code on the website of the charity I work for. I need to produce a report for our tech board on what we can fix easily, where the errors are coming from, all that good stuff.

I need to be able to automatically generate a spreadsheet for each of our page templates and be able to list the actions for each error. However I cannot find a validation tool that will output a CSV/spreadsheet, surely such a thing must exist.

For the record I have access to a Linux machine running Debian and Windows box at work if I need to install a tool locally to do this.

Please help me try to get our site accessable,

Matt H

Answer (score 0):

Could try this:

http://tools.daemonservices.com/html_to_csv/

Not used this before but should work fine for what you want.

Comment: unfortunately the w3c validator doesn't give it's output as a table, it's in a unordered list I was wondering if anyone knows of a standalone tool possibly?